# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. Cannot delete record

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

I'm trying to delete record from my "files" table. Here's the migration code:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');      // path to folder in storage and random generated name
        $table->string('visname');  // visible name
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('folder_id')->after('visname');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('author')->after('folder_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id')->after('project_id');
    
        $table->foreign('folder_id')->references('id')->on('folders');
        $table->foreign('author')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
    });
}
```

I'm using javascript to delete a record.

```js
function deleteFile(id) {
    var Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('fileId', id);
    Req.open("POST", "{{ route('deleteFile') }}")
    Req.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '{{csrf_token()}}');
    Req.onload = function (oEvent) {
        $(".file"+id).remove();
        console.log("Deleted");
    }
    Req.send(form);
}
```

And here is my controller

```php
public function deleteFile(Request $request)
{
    $file = File::find($request->fileId);
    $file->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 400
    ]);
}
```

Now when I try to delete file I'm getting error said in my question. Laravel generates query, for example
`delete from "files" where "id" = 2`

What's weird is that file in storage is deleted but database record stays intact.

Comment: Do you have any other table that has something like             `$table->foreign('...')->references('id')->on('files');` in yout other migrations?

Comment: whats weird is that you say the file is deleted, but you don't have any code for that

Comment: @Snapey it came to my knowleage that my colleague impemented a function on file model that deletes the file from storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in your other table schema. Most probably on some other table/schema you are using file_id as a foreign key. Make sure to add constraints on your other tables. One solution could be using **cascadeOnDelete()** or **nullOnDelete()**. What is happening here is when you are trying to delete the file here it is not letting you do so as it is referenced in some other table.

You can find more details here.
[Larave Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was long hidden bug that only recently surfaced due to different aproach to inserting data into table that stores information on who downloaded what file. Indeed there was a restrictOnDelete() inside that table schema.